# How to easily cherry pick with magit?

Tags: magit

I've been using magit for a few months now and I like it a lot. But one thing I still do it in a terminal is cherry picking.

What is a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Everywhere you see a commit in a Magit buffer, you can [cherry-pick](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Cherry-picking.html) it by moving point there and then typing <kbd>A A</kbd>. You can also cherry-pick multiple commits at once: just select some commits using the region and then press <kbd>A A</kbd>.

Answer (score 84):

### Magit version >= 2.1.0

For both methods, first start up `magit-status`.

**Method A**: *Cherry Pick changes from another branch one by one, or by ranges*

1. Press `l` and then `o` to get a list of other branches.
2. Select the branch you want to cherry pick from.
3. Move to the commit you need and press `A` followed by `A` again. You can also select the lines with the commit range you want with `C-space` and press `A` followed by `A` again.
4. The status line will show you which commit you selected

   e.g. `feature/ABC~4`

   Press `Enter` to apply changes.

**Method B**: *Cherry Pick all changes from another branch*

1. Press `A` to choose the cherry pick mode.
2. Press `A` again to apply and commit changes.
   Press `a` to only apply changes.
3. Choose a branch to cherry pick changes from and press `Enter`.

I personally prefer method A as you can handle merge conflicts better.

### Magit version <= 1.4.2

The workflow was different in earlier versions:

1. Enter overview `magit-status`
2. Check out (press `b b`) the branch you want to cherry pick into.
3. Do a log range (press `l r l`) to find the commits that you want to cherry pick. Here you select the 2 branches you want to compare.
4. Scroll to the commit you want to pick and press `A` to apply the changes and also stage them togeteher with the commit message. If you press `a` it will not stage the changes but only apply them.

You don't need to do a log range to cherry pick. Whenever you see a commit log you can press `A` to cherry pick it.

Comment: I did this wrong and it took me a bit to figure out why so here's to future readers: I was doing `l l o` inside the magit buffer instead of `l o`, this was causing my git to checkout the other branch instead of just showing its log (however it was hard to tell, because inside the log it looked like i was just looking at the other branch log without checking out). This was messing up my cherry-picking.

Comment: I don't always cherry pick. But when I do, I come to this answer every time.

Answer (score 9):

I don't use cherry picking, but hitting `?` in `magit-status` shows `y: Cherry`. This runs the command `magit-cherry`, which lets you pick a head and an upstream. It sounds like this is what you want.

You can type `C-h r d m Magit RET` to read the Magit manual. You can use `C-s cherry` and repeated hit `C-s` to search through the manual. Looks like the info is in section 23:

> One of the comforts of `git` is that it can tell you which commits have
>   been merged upstream but not locally and vice versa.  Git's sub-command
>   for this is `cherry` (not to be confused with `cherry-pick`).  Magit has
>   support for this by invoking `magit-cherry` which is bound to `y` by
>   default.
>
> Magit will then ask you first for the upstream revision (which
>   defaults to the currently tracked remote branch if any) and the head
>   revision (which defaults to the current branch) to use in the
>   comparison.  You will then see a new buffer in which all commits are
>   listed with a directional marker, their revision and the commit
>   message's first line.  The directional marker is either `+` indicating a
>   commit that's present in upstream but not in head or `-` which indicates
>   a commit present in head but not in upstream.
>
> **From this list you can use the usual key bindings for cherry-picking
>   individual commits (`a` for cherry-picking without committing and `A`
>   for the same plus the automatic commit).** The buffer is refreshed
>   automatically after each cherry-pick.

Comment: When invoking the Magit manual you can save a key stroke by doing `C-h i` instead of `C-h r d`. This will take you to the top-level of Info directly.

Comment: @itsjeyd Nahh, `C-h i` will take you to the last info file you opened, so if I hit `C-h i m`, I could potentially be looking at a menu of chapters in SICP instead of a menu of everything. Hitting `d` after `C-h i` or `C-h r` will ensure that you will be in the Info-directory when before you hit `m`.

Comment: That's a nice trick, I did not know about that! Also, totally off-topic: An Info version of SICP?! Where can I get a copy? :)

Comment: @itsjeyd I keep it in my Dropbox, I think I got it from here: https://github.com/webframp/sicp-info

Comment: Thanks! I checked MELPA and it turns out there is a package that gets built from that repository. So installing the Info version of SICP is as easy as `M-x` `package-install` `RET` `sicp` `RET` :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `Cherry` to better narrow down candidate commits:

Usually you want to pick some commits which are on `feature-a` but not on `released`, you can:

- create/checkout the branch you want to save the cherries to (name like `feature-a-subset`)
- `Cherry` in magit status buffer
- select `feature-a` as cherry head, `released` as upstream, to get some log of commits `feature-a` differ from `released`
- `Apply`->`Pick` (`A`->`A`) on some single commits or a region (*see more detail in tarsius and other's answers*)